# Qt translations for chinese appear as junk values

Tags: qt

I had generated 3 translation files using lupdate: French,Chinese and Hindi. I used linguist to do the required translations and then Released these translations.

In my main.cpp I wrote

```
QApplication a(argc,argv);
QTranslator translator;
translator.load("PaintTest_fr.qm");
a.installTranslator(&translator);
```

The french translations work fine. But Hindi (PaintText_hi.qm) and Chinese (PaintText_zh.qm) translations appear as junk values.

System Information:
Ubuntu 12.04

Qt version:
4.8.5

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any additional details to be specified for Asian languages? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: character encoding probably, try saving the qm files as UTF with BOM

Comment: @ratchetfreak I have saved it as utf-8. Not working.

Comment: Have you installed Chinese Unicode TrueType font? for example http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ttf-arphic-ukai

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new font for Chinese, such as "SimSun.ttf". Then it will work well. I just fixed this problem.